# disabling log4j in the common jar file

Tags: java, log4j

I have  problem with log4j.xml. I am using one common jar in my standalone application. The commom jar has its own log4j.xml file. The problem is my Unix server is not having the file structure specified in the common jar log4j.xml file so i am getting file not found error , when it tries to create log file. 
I have tried to override the log4j.xml file by writing a new log4j.xml file in my application. But still common jar is using its own log4j configuration. I am running my Application using a shell script. Can you please help in disabling or overriding log4 configuration in the common jar .either from java side or any shell script command.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Start the java application with `-Dlog4j.configuration=com/foo/bar/log4j.xml` in order to use a specific config file, overriding the one found in your jar, or make sure another log4j.xml is at the root of the classpath, *before* common.jar:

```
java -cp aDirectoryContainingLog4jXml;common.jar com.foo.bar.Main
```

Comment: Hi JB, Thanks working , I have simply added new log4j.xml file to classpath working fine . thanks for the quick response